# Is this considered a sloppy way to do it?

Tags: css, header

In my header div, I need to have 2 objects floating to the right, one is a button and the other is a search field.

Both of them is in a div called "pull-right" which just make them float right.

The objects are in these order (from the left to the right)

Searchbox
Button

However since both of them obviously float right, the first element in the code are going to win and take the spot on the right.

So I've placed the button before the searchbox, even though that the searchbox actually comes first. But it's still works.

Is it considered a sloppy way to do it?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navbar-inner" class="clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a href="#" class="btn lightgrey">Sign in</a>
   </div>

   <div class="pull-right">
     <form><input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"></form>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.pull-right { 
    float: right; 
}
```

Comment: The button should be part of the Searchbox, and not in a totally different node.

Comment: It's not related to the searchbox, it's a sign in button.

Comment: It helps to provide some code examples, so there is no confusion as to what you mean. Also, you may wish to look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for requests to code review.

Comment: Not providing any code and asking for opinions is probably a sloppy stackoverflow question :D

Comment: It's probably not sloppy. Markup and styling are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily wrap this in another container, and float that one to the right.

HTML:

```
<div id="floatingContainer">
    <input type="text" value="Input" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#floatingContainer { float:right; }​
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hYd9R/).

Comment: The problem is that the button is actually a link with a class style on it. That means I have to make both the Searchfield and the button float to the left inside of my pull-right div.